# How Can I keep dropdown caret symbol leftside in React JS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown like Arabic language modal so I need a dropdown caret symbol left side. How would I keep the dropdown caret on the leftside?

Sample:
[image: sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following attribute to the 'select' tag:

```
dir="rtl"
```

This will place the dropdown caret on the left

More information on direction : [CSS Tricks : Direction](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/)